# fancyhdr: Suppress header at the beginning of each chapter

Tags: fancyhdr

There are questions on this topic but I am still confused (because I still do not understand how the given answers work). How do I suppress the header at the beginning of each chapter?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Book}
\author{Me}

\makeatletter
\markboth{\textsc{\@title}}{\textsc{\@title}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\thepage}\quad\hrulefill}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\leftmark}\quad\hrulefill}
\fancyhead[CE]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\rightmark}\quad\hrulefill}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: The way it works is that `\chapter` includes `\thispagestyle{plain}`, but if you are already using plain, nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plain for the chapter pages and fancy for the rest:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Book}
\author{Me}

\makeatletter
\markboth{\textsc{\@title}}{\textsc{\@title}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\thepage}\quad\hrulefill}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\leftmark}\quad\hrulefill}
\fancyhead[CE]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\rightmark}\quad\hrulefill}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% for chapter pages
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\hrulefill\quad\raisebox{-3pt}{\thepage}\quad\hrulefill}%
 }

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```